# Popup on webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have a set of html webpages for my website. The website has been fully completed except for the popup, which is supposed to be loaded automatically when a user accesses the homepage of the website. This popup, which will be loaded in the middle of the homepage, will contain an image (900x400) with a close button on the top left of the popup.

I have tried numerous sources and many of these web resources require the user to click on the link for the popup to appear. I am not looking for the user to click to have the popup displayed. I want the user to be automatically shown the popup when the user accesses the homepage.

May someone please assist me through this issue?

Comment: somthing like: `$(document).ready( function() {  /* OPEN YOUR POPUP HERE */  });` ?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `div` with the CSS `position:absolute`, and create a `close` button for it:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {      
  document.querySelector('a.close').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.getElementById('language-popup').style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

```css
#language-popup {
  background-color: #AAAAFF;
  font-family: Verdana;
  padding: 12px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 900px;
  height: 400px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
}

#language-popup h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

#language-popup ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

#language-popup a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#language-popup a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

#language-popup .close {
  float: right;
}

#language-popup .close:hover {  
  text-decoration: none;
}

#language-popup .close:after {
  content: '✖';
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="language-popup">  
  <a class='close'></a>
  <h3>Popup title</h3>
  <section>
    Your popup content goes here!
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery UI Dialog. It can be shown anytime, onclick as well as onload of document. To implement it in your webpage, do this :

**HTML:**

```
<div id = "dialog">
<p>Some Content Here...</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#dialog').dialog();
});
```

Working [demo](https://www.jqueryui.com/dialog/) from jQueryUI.

> Make sure that you insert jQuery, jQueryUI and jQueryUI.CSS in your markup by placing these tags in your markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Comment: Unless it would be used extensively on the rest of the page/site, I think adding jQuery and jQueryUI here is a _bit_ overkill. At a push jQuery would be useful for animation, but even then CSS3 would suffice for this - [take a look at this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp)